# Google appengine flexible environment successfully deploys but web URL displays 404 error

Tags: google-app-engine, servlets, windows-10, google-cloud-sdk

I've been following this tutorial: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-firebase-app-engine-flexible

I reached the step titled "Deploying the service to the App Engine flexible environment", and initially could not get it to deploy due to dm:true being deprecated. Changing `<dm>true</dm>` to `<env>flex</env>` in "appengine-web.xml" fixed this, and it now appears in the App Engine console as "serving". However, when I go to access the printLogs URL as instructed in the tutorial (or any URL connected to the project for that matter) I run into a 404 error. I am deploying from Windows 10 through the command prompt, and have installed everything instructed by the tutorial. I cannot figure out what is causing the 404 despite being told that it is running correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go to the version in cloud platform and check the logs - it might tell you something.

However, I can tell you from experience that a lot of those projects are out of date and you can get all sorts of errors without changing a single line of code and following the instructions exactly.  I've some of them say that they deploy, only to have errors just like the one you are describing.

It is very likely that you are NOT doing something wrong - check out some of the other projects and look specifically at pom.xml (or build.gradle) and app.yaml.  See which versions of libraries they are including, and look for any differences.  Try deploying a very limited project, and then build upwards and see what is breaking the code.